# MySQL query within another query's while loop php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM season ORDER BY id";
$result = mysql_query($result, $con);
 while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $j = $res["id"];
   $s_writer="SELECT writer_id,name FROM s_writer,writer 
              WHERE s_id=$j AND writer_id=writer.id ORDER BY priority;";
   while ($writer = mysql_fetch_assoc($s_writer))
   {               
          <span> <?php echo $writer["name"]; ?></span>
   }
}
```

but this return null value

Comment: `<span> <?php echo $writer["name"]; ?></span>` syntax error for two reasons.

Comment: Instead of having this nested query structure consider looking into joins.

Comment: Try `WHERE s_id='".$res['id']."'` 
Remove the extra semicolon after priority ... should be "; not ;";

Comment: Also `<span> <?php echo $writer["name"]; ?></span>` should be `echo("<span>".$writer['name']."</span>);`